# keyboardType="number-pad" still shows decimal dot in Android

Tags: react-native

I just checked the RN [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#keyboardtype) and it seems that  `keyboardType="number-pad"` is cross-platform now, but when I use it I still get that `.` in my pad

[image]

P.S. I know the work around it and how to use Regex, but as the doc says this feature is now available cross-platform I wonder why it doesn't work!! shouldn't we trust the doc anymore!? :|

Comment: Use a regex for numbers only to exclude them before setting the state

Comment: @IanVasco   that's how I handled that before, but I was going to try that keyboardType="number-pad" as the doc says it's available cross-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android there is no way to control what buttons the keyboard shows.  The keyboard is a separate app and has full control over its UI.  The type is only a hint-  it gets to define what a number-pad is.  And each device can have its own separate keyboard app, so different devices may define it differently.  The only way around that is to write your own entire keyboard from scratch and include it in your app.  And I really do not suggest that.